# Scrapy spider crawl 0 page from Books to scrape website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a basic and straightforward `Scrapy` spider to crawl`https://books.toscrape.com/`.

No parse function has been implemented yet, and I want to see if the spider can crawl the website.

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider' 
    allowed_domains = ["tosrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="catalogue/category")),
    )
```

Even though I'm able to interact with the website via the `Scrapy` shell (e.g. `response.css("a::text").getall()`) but the crawler doesn't crawl the website and returns :

```
2023-03-02 14:31:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-03-02 14:31:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-03-02 14:31:05 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-03-02 14:31:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://books.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-03-02 14:31:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://books.toscrape.com/> (referer: None)
2023-03-02 14:31:07 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'books.toscrape.com': <GET https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index.html>
2023-03-02 14:31:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
...
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 ...
2023-03-02 14:31:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I should deactivate offset middleware.

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   "MyProject.middlewares.WebcrawlingSpiderMiddleware": 543,
   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware': None
}
```

Scrapy documentation [Spider Middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `allowed_domains`. It should be  `books.toscrape.com` instead of `tosrape.com`.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider' 
    allowed_domains = ["books.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="catalogue/category")),
    )
```